# How to run google chrome with "--single-process" on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome on my Ubuntu 14.04. I wonder that Google Chrome runs different processes for different opened tabs. By googling I found that, in this case google chrome with "--single-process" can solve this problem. But, how can I set my google chrome to run with "--single-process" flag?
In windows it can be done by right clicking on the shortcut of Google Chrome, then in target box we can set --single-process as shown on the given picture.
Help please if you know the soln!!!
[set up google chrome on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lctFj.png)

Comment: As far as I know the recent versions of chrome do not support that option anymore, so you'll probably have to compile an older one from source... which of course is not very advisable due to the lack of new features, security patches, etc...

Comment: @SledgeHammer
But I think I got the solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated by [hg8](https://askubuntu.com/a/698711/119531) to run Google Chrome as a single process, type in terminal:

```
google-chrome-stable --single-process
```

But to make it permanent, i.e, to run Chrome as a single process on clicking on launcher icon, do the following:

1. Install alacarte:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install alacarte
   ```
2. Open alacarte.
3. Goto Internet > Google Chrome.
4. Click on the "Properties" box present on the right side of the window.

   Here's a screenshot to help you better understand the process.

   [image: 1]
5. Change

   ```
   /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
   ```

   in the command box to

   ```
   /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --single-process %U
   ```
6. Close the window.
7. Also, you may now remove alacarte that you have installed before by typing:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge alacarte
   ```

Comment: Ok!! It is working.

Comment: @ShikhorRoy - Glad! If it helped you then please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: But while I open Google Chrome then it is showing a warning:
"You are using unsupported command-line flag: --single-process. Stability and security will suffer"!!!

Comment: @ShikhorRoy - Yes, because you are running it as a single process, which is not recommended. This error is also shown when you run it from terminal using the command.

Comment: OK, I AC your ans, but sorry to say you that I haven't total 15 repu. so I can't up vote your ans. :p
Thanks. :)

Comment: @ShikhorRoy - Its ok. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Simply open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
google-chrome-stable --single-process
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Actually, If i can then I give you an up vote!!! :)

Comment: Ok. I've found that the command is working for each time I have run it...but how can I set "--single-process" up permanently to google chrome?

Comment: @ShikhorRoy like mentioned in the comment on your question, the command is depricated. Even the called window mentions that. Is that not what happens on your system?

Comment: @JacobVlijm
I found this on my command window:
[5418:5453:1116/224350:ERROR:proxy_service_factory.cc(129)] Cannot use V8 Proxy resolver in single process mode.
[5418:5453:1116/224351:ERROR:proxy_service_factory.cc(129)] Cannot use V8 Proxy resolver in single process mode.
[5418:5453:1116/224458:ERROR:channel.cc(307)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)